# Thread for member functions

Tags: c++

I was trying to make threads for the following function

```
void SortingCompetition::masterSort(int low, int high)
```

like this:

```
  thread a(&SortingCompetition::masterSort,this, low, j-1);
    thread b (&SortingCompetition::masterSort,this, j+1,high);
```

and get the following error.

```
sortingcompetition.cpp:55:16: error: no matching constructor for initialization
  of 'std::__1::thread'
    thread b (&SortingCompetition::masterSort,this, j+1,high);
           ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:374:9: note: 
  candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__f',
  but 4 arguments were provided
thread::thread(_Fp __f)
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:263:5: note: 
  candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 4 were provided
thread(const thread&);
^
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:270:5: note: 
  candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 4 were
  provided
thread() _NOEXCEPT : __t_(0) {}
```

I'm new to threads, so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You need to use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to specify an object instance that should be used to call the member function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [bind](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) the method like:

```
thread a(std::bind(&SortingCompetition::masterSort, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2),low,j-1);
```

Alternative you can use a function or static method. The reason is, that due binding the `this` pointer is preserved. To invoke the method of an instance wich is not static, you need the `this` pointer. With `std::bind` this is done. `std::bind` needs to now how many parameters the method has, thats where the placeholder come into game.